# A TVS for lightning surge protection

Tags: ethernet, surge-protection, tvs, lightning, network-interface

A camera will be mounted outside and powered via POE to Aruba 2540 network switch. I don't want indirect lightning surge to travel into the network switch. I don't care if the camera gets destroyed.

The ethernet line to line voltage is 54V, and the requirement that I have is that the TVS should clamp lighting surge upto 2000V or 400Amps.

What kind of circuit would I need for lightning protection with a TVS?

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic here but you should just search the Digikey or Mouser website, or the Littelfuse catalog.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.amazon.com/Ethernet-Surge-Protector-Protectnet-1000/dp/B07QS3R7W3/ref=asc_df_B07QS3R7W3/?tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=343991705271&hvpos=1o4&hvnetw=g&hvrand=17609615474292826942&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9014308&hvtargid=pla-770551158418&psc=1&tag=&ref=&adgrpid=69534739856&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvadid=343991705271&hvpos=1o4&hvnetw=g&hvrand=17609615474292826942&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9014308&hvtargid=pla-770551158418

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A TVS diode is probably not going to be enough to protect your equipment from a surge caused by lightning. Generally you'll want to use gas discharge tubes to take the brunt of the surge, then either inductors or dedicated Bourns TBU surge protectors, followed by TVS diodes to minimize the residual surge. Here is a fairly standard surge protection scheme that is used all over the place for exactly this purpose:

[image]

Obviously you'll need to change the values of the TVS diodes, but this should give you an idea. Also, if your system doesn't mind a slightly higher series resistance, replace the inductors with TBU surge protectors, as I mentioned earlier.

**EDIT:**

Note that this is a double-sided protection circuit, meaning it can protect against surges from either direction. If this protection circuit is to be placed right next to the device which is to be protected, you may eliminage L3, L4, and SA2. Keep TZ1, TZ3, and the earth connection between them though. The device being protected should then be connected where L3 and L4 used to be, across TZ2 and TZ3.

Comment: If I were to use any components , it will ask me for a clamping voltage. Do I measure the voltage between line to line or line to ground for Voltage clamping?

Comment: I measured the line to line voltage and found that it is 54V. Does that mean I need a component with 54V as its clamping voltage?

Comment: @Kasap23 Probably the reverse standoff voltage, not breakdown. TVS diode thresholds are not exactly precise so you want to ensure that it never breaks down in the normal operating range. Reverse standoff/holdoff voltage is what it is guaranteed to not break down. Breakdown is when it starts to conduct. And clamping is the voltage drop when it is conducting a specified amount of current.

Comment: Got it. I may still have few more question. I will ask as I learn. Thank you

Comment: If I put a tvs diode between line to line, then the tvs would act as a short and the current would go to line instead of ground. Isn't that bad? Shouldn't I be creating a ground path? if I do create a ground path, then how do I determine the reverse standoff voltage?

Comment: @Kasap23 You already have one though with TZ2 and TZ3. It's possible for the lines two get too far apart in voltage with neither ever actually getting too far from ground. That's what TZ1 is for. Shorting out a desired source of power is bad...but a lightning surge is not a desired source of power. You don't want to tire out your power supply by shorting it out, but you definitely want a lightning surge to tire itself out before reaching your electronics. You don't want to overwork the horse that's pulling your wagon, but you do want to tire out the ogre that's going around smashing stuff.

Comment: For the specific circuit shown above, what is the voltage of line to line, and how did he determine TZ1, TZ2 and TZ3? Can you pleas explain. I am doing my best to figure out and understand.

Comment: You just choose what you expect the voltage to be during operation. You expect 54V across TZ1 so pick 54V or a bit higher. Since TZ2 and TZ3 see also see 54V across them, then you definitely don't want their sum to be less than 54V. But a safe bet is just to make each one 54V too, especially if one of the lines is neutral and connected to earth somewhere. I am not sure where the 7.5V he has is coming from since it clearly says 230V on the plugs. You'll have to ask him.

Comment: @Kasap23 BTW, depending on how you are measuring that 54V, that might be 54Vrms. You want the peak voltage since that is the highest instantaneous voltage that will actually appear on the line, not RMS.

Comment: OMG, I am learning so much. Thank you. How important is the gas discharge tube? I am looking at tvs diode and it seems that there are tvs diode that follows that standard DO-160, and also how does waveform matter? It seem I need to move to a different discussion, since the discussion is long.

Comment: @Kasap23 I've been told a gas discharge tube is the only thing that is able to absorbs the power from a lightning strike. Waveform is tricky. There are standardized test waveforms that are used to rate components, but the waveform you experience in real life doesn't always (or often) match up with what the test waveform used to rate the component. In the same way I'm sure you have experienced many different types of static shocks that feel different in more than just strength. It's kind of an art.

Comment: Awesome. I learned a lot. I will create a new post on waveform and gas discharge tube. For now I believe this helped. Thank you

Comment: My apologies for the delay. The 230V label on the gas discharge tube is indicating the DC spark-over voltage, showing when the GDT is intended to start conducting. Once it conducts, the voltage seen by the rest of the protection circuit is simply the voltage drop across the arc within the tube, which is relatively low. This is how the GDT takes the brunt of the surge. As for the 7.5V TVS value, that is the reverse standoff (working) voltage of the device. Our product is designed to handle 7.5V, so we don't want the TVS conducting during normal operation

Comment: The TVS didoe we use has a breakdown voltage of 8.33V and a clamping voltage of 12.9V. This means that the TVS begins to conduct around 8.33V (roughly) and, when conducting the specified peak current, holds the line at 12.9V. Our circuit being protected can technically handle 12.9V without being damaged, so this is sufficient. It is very important to find a diode with a clamping voltage *less* than the max specified by the parts in your circuit. Re. placement, the scheme I posted prevents the lines from being separated by more than 12.9V, and keeps each line within 12.9V of ground

Comment: @DerStrom8 Oh, that's the symbol for a gas discharge tube? I thought it was a mains plug lol. The really low TVS voltage makes more sense now.

Comment: @Kasap23 He replied.

Comment: Since I am putting tvs diode from ethernet line to ground, can I put two tvs diode in series to reduce the capacitance from line to ground. A signal tvs diode with higher capacitance will affect the data. What do you think about it?