# Lightning Surge Protector that complies with DO-160. Indirect lightning waveform, Gas Discharge tube or MOV in parallel with tvs

Tags: waveform, surge-protection, tvs, lightning

Would it be wise to put Gas discharge tube in parallel with tvs diode?

OR

Would it be better to put MOV in parallel with tvs diode?

Also when deciding on tvs diode, how does indirect lightning surge waveform come to play?

I need to put a lightning surge protector in line with a power over ethernet cable. I am asking this question in order to build a lightning surge protection that complies with DO-160.

Comment: Since this is related to your previous question, I will add a link to that question so that other readers can see some more of the context; "[A TVS for lightning surge protection](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/464214)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you did, it would be wise to also put series resistance in between the Gas Discharge Tube (GDT) and the TVS against the worst case scenario like this:

[image]
Source: https://www.eenewsled.com/content/tvs-surge-protection-devices-protect-your-electronics

The series resistance would be dependent on the load, and how much current the TVS could take before failure.

If using on ethernet, the transformer already acts as a barrier, most have 2kV, some have more (I've seen up to 6kV). If desired the phy can be protected from discharges that travel through the small amount of capacitance that exists between the windings in the transformer. If you do use a TVS, make sure it has a small amount of capacitance (under 1pF) or use for highspeed applications,

[image]
Source: https://incompliancemag.com/article/designing-ethernet-cable-ports-to-withstand-lightning-surges/

Comment: Since this is an ethernet line, wouldn't putting resistor decrease the data transmission rate.

Comment: There are a lot of tvs diode that has DO-160 approved, would that be enough.

Comment: If it were me I'd get an ethernet transformer that was higher than 2kV and call it good.

Comment: Ethernet transformer... I will look into it. Thank you. I may have question later about this.

Comment: I don't understand why there is a need for R2 and R3 on the Ethernet PHY chip. Wouldn't the tvs diode and the ethernet transformer be enough?

Comment: Many TVS devices have significant package parasitics and although the models imply picosecond engagement time, the *real* engagement time is more like 500 nanoseconds. A device where the TVS is *directly bonded to the pads* will be much faster.

Comment: You've changed the question three times now

Comment: @petersmith the TVS's will also advertise high speed there are some that are good for usb 2.0 Ethernet ect